# Flask authenticantion. How to inform the user logged in the client to the server

Tags: flask, active-directory

I am creating a flask app to be used internally in my company. I would like to restrict what a user can do it based on its login ID. I read a lot about using LDAP3 but I don't think I can do what want which send the login ID to the server. There I would have a table which will register which part of the system has the permition to edit. If it try to change somenthing not permited the app will retrieve a warning message.

I won't to do that to avoid having to create a separate login functionality just for this app. I read that I should use AD authentication but I am not very familiarized with that and I would also like to avoid having to ask our IT department to create user groups there for each part of my system.

I know that I can do that using ASP .NET (at least I did once).

Any guidance will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Role-based Authorization.](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authorization.html)

In order to use this functionality you will need to implement roles on your model file [per the Data-models documentation.](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_models.html#roleanduserroledatamodels)

This will allow you to assign users a role when they are created, and you can use a decorator on your routes to 'require' the user to have the role you want them to have before they access the endpoint.

Comment: Ok but how can I get the user that is requesting the view? For exemple every day I log on my company computer with my login account. I want that when I access my app it knows it is me (or someone else). I know how to check the user name locally but I trying to find a way to send this inforamtion to the server.